# reading qrcode in python gives empty in terminal

Tags: python

I have a problem reading qrcode data from image (not using webcam just get qrcode.png and read it) I'm using pyqrcode module to generate my qrcodes and it works well and when I read it using any mobile phone built in reader it gives me correct data without any problems but when I try to read it using python the output is always "[]" empty bracket so where's the problem

```
    print(data)
    dest = str(data)
    myQR = QRCode(dest, encoding = 'utf-8')
    myQR.show()
    myQR.png('QR.png', scale=8)
```

this how i create qrcode and i prefer not using (cv2 or zbar) cuz I have problem downloading zbar

*edit*
built in readers in mobile phones reads it correctly without any errors and gives me correct data

Comment: is this your whole code? if not can you post it because from here is not simple to understand

Comment: sadly I can't post the full code here but I can say what is the data it's basically numpy array

Comment: if we don't know how your code works we can't find out the problem and search for a solution